# JavaScript variable split into groups

Tags: javascript, variables, split

have a `var id = "123456789";`

how to split in into groups after each 3 digits??

result must be like this:

```
var no1 = 123;
var no2 = 456;
var no3 = 789;
```

if the id will be longer 12, 15 or more digits, should work the same!

Comment: i asked to help and to minus this article

Comment: thanks for help guys, i had a stress with such a simple thing, but it works pretty to me now!

Comment: Hope you moved away from using multiple vars and decided to use an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be your answer, use this function per your need, the `output` array contains the result

```
function parseDigits()
{
    var number = 123456789,
    output = [],
    sNumber = number.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 3) {
        output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i)+sNumber.charAt(i+1)+sNumber.charAt(i+2));
    }

    alert(output);

}
```

Comment: thanks for help, i had a stress with such a simple thing, but it works pretty to me now!

Answer (score 1):

Can this work ?

```
var id = "123456789"
var arr = id.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

Here:

```
arr[0] == "123"
arr[1] == "456" ....
```

Better to get the values using `substring()`. Do check for the length before performing `substring()` to save yourself from *IndexOutOfBounds* sort of errors.

Comment: and how to save each group in variable??

Answer (score 1):

```
var splittedArray = yourString.match(/.../g);
```

that way you'll get the array of all your values :)

Comment: and how to save each group in variable??

Comment: you can't guess how many variable you'll get :)

Comment: you can then do a loop like this:
for (var i=0; i<splittedArray.length; i++) { splittedArray[i] is your variable }

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i+=3){
    result.push(id.substring(i, i + 3));
}
```

If you want exact result(stored in no variables):

```
for(var i = 0, j = 1; i < id.length; i+=3, j++){
    window['no' + j] = id.substring(i, i + 3);
}

console.log(no1);
console.log(no2);
console.log(no3);
```